# get tasks where all task tags is in path tags

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

My code returns `tasks` where one of **Task Tags** name `->(tasktags)` is in Path Tags->$TagArray .

I want to get `Tasks` where all **Task Tags** (`tasktags`) are in **Path Tags** array `->$TagArray`.

```
$posts4 = Path::with(['pathtags' => function ($q) use ($TagArray) {
    $q->with(['Tasks'=>function($q) use ($TagArray) { 
        $q->has('tasktags', '=' , 2)->whereHas('tasktags', function ($query) use 
            ($TagArray) {
            $query->whereIn('name',$TagArray);

        })->with('tasktags');
    }]);
}])->first()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `whereHas` with `whereDoesntHave` and `whereIn` with `whereNotIn` like so:

```
whereDoesntHave('tasktags', function ($query) use 
    ($TagArray) {
        $query->whereNotIn('name',$TagArray);
 })
```

Comment: Thanks Man you saved My life

Comment: Can you check My Error please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52952144/return-view-is-returning-different-data