# return view is returning different data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

everybody, My code here is returning tasks that have more than 1 Tag and task tags are in $TagArray everything is working good in

```
return $TaskData;
```

but When I pass TaskData into view I get different results even get Tasks with one tag

```
return view ('task', compact('TaskData'));
```

My Code

```
$TaskData= Path::with(['pathtags' => function ($q) use ($TagArray) {
    $q->with(['Tasks' => function($q) use ($TagArray) { 
        $q->has('tasktags', '=' , 2)->whereDoesntHave('tasktags', 
            function ($query) use ($TagArray) {
                $query->whereNotIn('name', $TagArray);
            }
        )->with('tasktags');
    }]);
}])->first();
```

Comment: Was is the output when you `dd($TaskData)`? and What do you want to achieve?

Comment: the output of dd($TaskData) same as return $TaskDAta   but it is different in return view it return all tasks

Comment: So you want to get only one task inside the `$TaskData`

Comment: No i have path that have many tags every tag have many tasks   every task have many tags

Comment: i need to get tasks where there tags is in $TagArray and i did it  and have more than one tag

Comment: but when i return it in view it get all tasks i get all tasks in path tags even one that has one tag

Comment: post your view code

Comment: i already did  return view ('task', compact('TaskData'));